# Passing string by ref to activex component in C#

Tags: c#, com, activex

I'm trying to us an ActiveX API function with the pattern `function(ref string returnvalue)` in C#. The API function modifies the string.

```
string returnValue = String.Empty;
api.func(ref returnValue); // DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH
```

OK, maybe that's because strings are immutable. Trying a `StringBuilder` per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#cpcondefaultmarshalingforstringsanchor3):

```
StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder(128);
api.func(returnValue);
```

This causes a compile-time error about type mismatch.

How do I call this function?

I don't know if I need to marshal the C# string to a BStr, and if so, I don't know how to pass that by ref to the API function.

Comment: Immutability does not mean you can´t re-reference a variable . It simply means it´s internal value does not change. But with ref-keyword you simply reference a NEW string, so you won´t need a stringBuilder at all

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know what you mean ... I'm calling a method from an API.

Comment: Start the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  Run oleview.exe, use File + View Typelib and select the ActiveX executable.  What does 'api.func' *really* look like in that program?

Comment: @HansPassant at the moment I get `TYPE_E_CANNOTLOADLIBRARY` when opening it from oleview; trying to fix that. I'm not sure what you would expect to see -- the object browser shows the signature `int func(ref string returnValue)`.

Comment: Could you attach screen?

Comment: @HansPassant finally got it, `long func(BSTR* returnValue);`

Comment: That is correct.  It doesn't have anything to do with the way you call it, the function itself fails when it calls something else.  Contact the owner or author for support.

Comment: Update: I can call the API from C++ without problem. That seems to suggest bad marshalling from C#?

Answer (score 0):

If `func` should change `returnValue` , I think your code should be changed like this:

```
string returnValue = String.Empty;
api.func(ref returnValue);
```

You should init `returnValue` before pass it by [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

**UPD:** Did you try to call it like this?:

```
api.func(ref Marshal.StringToBSTR(string value));
```

Comment: Indeed `func` should change `returnValue`. Using your suggestion causes `Type mismatch (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)` unfortunately.

Comment: Could you add name of ActiveX API function or attach it? Because looks like problem is little bit deeper.

Comment: It's a very rare API that has no documentation online. Something from the same manufacturer is on page 30 of http://www.velocity11.com/techdocs/previoususerguides/VSpin/July2002/VSpinUserGuide_July2002.pdf.

Comment: @ZachB I wan't to help, but I haven't enough info for it. I've added some UPD maybe it will help you. Good luck.

Comment: Re: update, yeah, tried explicitly marshalling to a BSTR, but that gives an IntPtr and thus a type-mismatch. That should be the default marshalling anyway. Thanks for the help, sorry for the tricky problem without much useful info.

Answer (score -1):

Call it with a reference to a `string` variable, as it says:

```
string returnValue = "";
api.func(ref returnValue);
```

You might want to take a look at the [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) and [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) keywords in C#.

Comment: That causes a compile-time error "Use of unassigned local variable" or runtime error, `DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH` if I assign `""` to the string.

Comment: @HimBromBeere ZachB never said it causes both. He said that if he doesn't assign `""`, it causes a compile-time error, and if he does, it causes a runtime error. Those are two different scenarios.